# multiple and or logic in php if statement not working

Tags: php, if-statement, logic, logical-operators

I have gone round and round with this and I can't seem to get the logic correct for what I want.

Here is the code:

```
   function fetchFile() {
    global $directory;
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        global $sampleIssue,$freeIssue;
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `volume`,`number`,`EditorMessage` FROM `articles` WHERE `id`='$id';");
        $article = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if 
        (($article['volume']!=$sampleIssue['vol'] || $article['number']!=$sampleIssue['no']) || ($article['EditorMessage']==='N')
         && ($article['volume']!=$freeIssue['vol'] || $article['number']!=$freeIssue['no'])){
    global $needsLogin;
            $needsLogin = TRUE;
        }
```

Basically I need for the login to be true or if any of the three conditions are met:

```
$article['volume']!=$sampleIssue['vol'] || $article['number']!=$sampleIssue['no']
OR
$article['EditorMessage']==='N'
OR
$article['volume']!=$freeIssue['vol'] || $article['number']!=$freeIssue['no']
```

I have tried switch cases too and I am just not getting it.

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: Thanks Charlotte, I am trying to get it to work with mysql first as this is code I did not write and I want to fix one thing at a time.